# Symfony2 Doctrine Configuration

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create database on my ubuntu using doctrine.

This is my Synfony2 app/parameters.yml :

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: perfect
database_user: root
database_password: *******
database_path: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ebc9434674a8e1e3bc42ef35a500407c24c14d61
```

But when I'm trying to run  php app/console doctrine:database:create in my project I receives an error:

```
Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

But why connection name is 'symfony'? And why I can't create this DB?

I was trying to set database port, clear cache, restart mysql and nothing.
(my PDO is avaliable).

Comment: Please post your config.yml

Comment: This is my config.yml   http://pastebin.com/eiTnPKHN

Comment: Ok I solved a problem :) Just run mysql and next SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('*******'), cleared cache by sudo app/console cache:clear --env=prod
and its working :) TY

Answer (score -2):

Connection name is not the same as schema name. Connection name can be configured in `config.yml`. Your problem is in the bad credentials. As you see from Error you doesn't provide any password. Maybe you have password for root user? Or maybe you doesn't grant access for root from localhost. On my OS X system I have strange behavior: localhost - only works for socket connections but 127.0.0.1 - for TCP/IP.

Check your connection settings. Try to google advice for configuring MySQL for your OS.

Comment: This is not really a helpfull answer. The hint to the config.yml should be a comment to the TO

Comment: Why not? Did you read questions? Why connection name is symfony? I answered that it is set in config.yml. Next question: "Why I can't create this DB?"... He has bad credentials. Two questions - two right answers. If he has problem how to set up MySQL DB schema properly he can ask another question for that. It would be more useful for community.

Comment: Because you say the error is in the config.yml, but this doesn't help him. If you know the error may located in a config file, you should ask the TO in a comment to post his config file, and don't write such unhelpful answers.

Comment: I didn't say that error in `config.yml` I just said that connection name by default is set in `config.yml`. I said that the problem is in credentials. And it must be set properly.

Comment: You can't know the problem without seeing the config.yml. Maybe the parameters have a typo.. In such cases you should ask the TO for more informations and don't guess answers

Comment: I pasted my config.yml in comment